# How to configure nullmailer to work with mailchimp?

Tags: mail, smtp

As my title said i have some problem with configuration of nullmailer.
Basicaly I have been following [this](https://opensourcehacker.com/2013/03/25/using-nullmailer-and-mandrill-for-your-ubuntu-linux-server-outboud-mail/) website.

I have made an account on Mailchimp - where I have send succesfully the test mail. On my machine i have installed Nullmailer:

Then I have configure the remotes:

```
smtp.mandrillapp.com smtp --port=587 --starttls --user=ttomek.koziak@gmail.com --pass=boo
```

I have set the adminaddr

```
cat /etc/nullmailer/adminaddr 
ttomek.koziak@gmail.com
```

The defaultdomain remains empty

This is how my mail.log looks like:

**EDIT**
After adding `--insecure` flag

```
Jun 13 17:06:23 tom-VirtualBox postfix/cleanup[5176]: 9A8C31A68: message-id=<20190613150623.9A8C31A68@tom-VirtualBox.home>
Jun 13 17:06:23 tom-VirtualBox postfix/qmgr[5047]: 9A8C31A68: from=<root@tom-VirtualBox.home>, size=345, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jun 13 17:06:24 tom-VirtualBox postfix/smtp[5178]: connect to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2a00:1450:4010:c03::1b]:25: Network is unreachable
Jun 13 17:06:25 tom-VirtualBox postfix/smtp[5178]: 9A8C31A68: to=<ttomek.koziak@gmail.com>, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[209.85.233.27]:25, delay=1.8, delays=0.45/0.09/0.67/0.61, dsn=5.7.1, status=bounced (host gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[209.85.233.27] said: 550-5.7.1 [89.64.27.89] The IP you're using to send mail is not authorized to 550-5.7.1 send email directly to our servers. Please use the SMTP relay at your 550-5.7.1 service provider instead. Learn more at 550 5.7.1  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=NotAuthorizedError p3si308852ljp.41 - gsmtp (in reply to end of DATA command))
Jun 13 17:06:25 tom-VirtualBox postfix/cleanup[5176]: 8345A1AFF: message-id=<20190613150625.8345A1AFF@tom-VirtualBox.home>
Jun 13 17:06:25 tom-VirtualBox postfix/qmgr[5047]: 8345A1AFF: from=<>, size=2986, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jun 13 17:06:25 tom-VirtualBox postfix/bounce[5179]: 9A8C31A68: sender non-delivery notification: 8345A1AFF
Jun 13 17:06:25 tom-VirtualBox postfix/qmgr[5047]: 9A8C31A68: removed
Jun 13 17:06:25 tom-VirtualBox postfix/local[5180]: 8345A1AFF: to=<root@tom-VirtualBox.home>, relay=local, delay=0.32, delays=0.08/0.21/0/0.03, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to mailbox)
Jun 13 17:06:25 tom-VirtualBox postfix/qmgr[5047]: 8345A1AFF: removed
```

But I do not really know where to go from this point. Any Ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: Did you try the `--insecure` flag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the fix was in the end quite simple.

I needed to allow less secure application access [here](https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps?utm_source=google-account&utm_medium=web). As well as `--insecure` flag in the remote file was necessary.